# why the box turn over when set velocity?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi friends, I am following this tutorial [Model plugins](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin).

In this tutorial, set a volocity to the box:

```
this->model->SetLinearVel(ignition::math::Vector3d(.3, 0, 0));
```

but when simulate, the box turn over, like this:
[image: image description]

so why? is it a bug? thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23625/why-the-box-turn-over-when-set-velocity?/) by [Lays](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14571/lays/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If the box and the ground has the coefficient of friction bigger than 0, this behavior is correct. The box gets caught by the floor and tripps over. Just as in real life.

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lays](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14571/lays/) on 2019-08-28**:
thanks， but how to change the coefficient of friction?  In the gui, I did not find how to change it.

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2019-08-28**:
You can set it in GUI:

```
right click on the model -> Edit Model  -> right click on the link -> Open Link Inspector -> Collision tab ->  drop down the collision -> Srurface/Friction/Mu edit value
```

Or in [SDF](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=collision) code:

```
<model>
...
   <link>
    ...
      <collision>
      ... 
         <surface>
             <friction>
                 <ode>
                     <mu>1.0</mu>
                 </ode>
             </friction>
        </surface>
...
```